# How do you edit a repeatedly initialized label?

Tags: java, label, swt

Let's say I made a swt and a button triggers this line of code:

```
    Label Charname = new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
    Charname.setBounds(250,10+a,500,40);
    Charname.setText("Hello");
    a=a+40;
```

I press the button twice, so it makes 2 labels, like so:

```
    hello
    hello
```

If I wanted to .getText the FIRST label, how would I do so? I know these labels are both the same but this is just a example, in what I'm working in these labels are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to remember the labels you have created so you can access them again. One way would be to save them in a list in your class.

```
public class MyClass {

    List<Label> labels = new ArrayList<>();

    .... other code


    Label charname = new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
    ...

    // Save in the list
    labels.add(charname);

    .....

    // Access old label
    int index = ... index of label required
    Label oldLabel = labels.get(index);

}
```